# SAS: Concat columns from different tables (same number of rows)

Tags: merge, sas

I have two tables with the same number of rows but not one column I could join them toghether. Like:

```
data table1(keep=Model) table2(keep=MSRP);
    set sashelp.cars;
run;
```

How cound I concat table1 and table2 in order to achieve:

[image]

In python I would do it as `pandas.concat([table1, table2], axis=1)` but here anything I try like:

```
data cancated;
    set table1 table2;
run;
```

or

```
proc sql;
    create table joined as
    select * from table1
    union 
    select * from table2;

    delete from joined where Model is missing or MSRP is missing;
run;
```

but especially the second one gave me error:

> ERROR: Column 1 from the first contributor of UNION is not the same
>   type as its counterpart from the second.

So if I udnerstand corectly I cannot have this kind of join with different types of variables.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that this is not good data management practice to assume that the observations are actually in matching order without any identifier variables that can be used to verify that you are combining the right observations. Just because you can do it doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @Tom Thank you for your note. In my specific case I will have always the same number of rows and the same order - therefore your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `merge` statement without any `by` statement to get a row-by-row matching of the observations from two or more datasets.

```
data concated;
  merge table1 table2;
run;
```

You could also just use separate `set` statements for each dataset.

```
data concated;
  set table1;
  set table2;
run;
```

The difference will be when the two datasets have different number of observations. With `merge` the number of observations will match that of the larger dataset. (The variables contributed only from the smaller dataset will have their values retained.)  With the `set` statements the result will only have the number of observations in the smaller dataset. The step will end when either of the `set` statements reads past the end of the input dataset.

Answer (score 1):

to do something like in your query. you need to use row number as shown below and then join and delete.

```
 data table1(keep=Model var) table2(keep=MSRP var);
set sashelp.cars;
var = _n_;
run;

 proc sql;
 create table joined(drop=var) as 
 select a.*, b.* from table1 a
 full join table2 b
 on a.var = b.var;

 delete from joined where Model is missing or MSRP is missing
 ;
```